# Searching through an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, search, return

I'm attempting to return the index of where an object appears in an array of objects.

```
public static int search(WordCount[] list,WordCount word, int n)
{
    int result = -1;
    int i=0;
    while (result < 0 && i < n)
    {
        if (word.equals(list[i]))
        {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`WordCount[]` is the array of objects.

`word` is an instance of `WordCount`.

`n` is the number of objects in `WordCount[]`

It runs, but isn't returning the index correctly. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

CLASS

```
class WordCount
{
String word;
int count;
static boolean compareByWord;
public WordCount(String aWord)
{
    setWord(aWord);
    count = 1;
}
private void setWord(String theWord)
{
    word=theWord;
}
public void increment()
{
    count=+1;
}
public static void sortByWord()
{
    compareByWord = true;
}
public static void sortByCount()
{
    compareByWord = false;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result = String.format("%s (%d)",word, count);
    return result;
}
}
```

How I'm calling it...

```
for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].length()>0)
            {
                WordCount word = new WordCount(tokens[i]);
                int foundAt = search(wordList, word, n);
                if (foundAt >= 0)
                {
                    wordList[foundAt].increment();
                }
                else
                {
                    wordList[n]=word;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is it returning?

Comment: Show us your `equals` implementation for `WordCount`.

Comment: Have you overridden the equals() and hashCode() methods in WordCount?

Comment: It is supposed to return the index of where `word` is found in `WordCount`.

Comment: @Radiodef what do you mean by that? This is my first java program i've written with a class so this is all new to me

Comment: According to the comment, you have created your own class `WordCount`, but you have **not** overridden the `equals` method. Post your `WordCount` class, and you'll receive help quickly.

Comment: @Bob What anubian noob meant was, when you run the program, what is actually being returned from the loop?

Comment: Bob: You have created a new class called `WordCount` but unlike other Java objects you cannot just compare these using the .equals() method as it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: If you've not overridden `equals` then it is comparing references, the same as `==`. If you have overridden `equals` then you may have not done it correctly. You should also show to us how you are calling `search`.

Comment: I have posted the class and how I'm using `search` in my main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) just returns whether or not the two references refer to the same object (same as the `==` operator). Looking at what you are doing, what you need to do is create a method in your `WordCount` to return `word`, e.g.:

```
public String getWord() {
    return word;
}
```

Then change your comparison in `search` from:

```
if (word.equals(list[i]))
```

to:

```
if (word.getWord().equals(list[i].getWord()))
```

Or change the signature of the method to accept a `String` so you don't create a new object if you don't have to.

I wouldn't recommend overriding `equals` in `WordCount` so that it uses only `word` to determine object equality because you have other fields. (For example, one would also expect that two counters were equal only if their counts were the same.)

The other way you can do this is to use a `Map` which is an associative container. An example is like this:

```
public static Map<String, WordCount> getCounts(String[] tokens) {
    Map<String, WordCount> map = new TreeMap<String, WordCount>();

    for(String t : tokens) {
        WordCount count = map.get(t);
        if(count == null) {
            count = new WordCount(t);
            map.put(t, count);
        }

        count.increment();
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: thanks man I had no idea it was as simple as throwing a getWord function into my class. Been stewing over this issue for the last 3 hours. For some reason my increment isn't working though? When I print out the output it is only printing a (1) for all the words. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I'm an idiot, found my problem. I really appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

This method is probably not working because the implementation of .equals() you are using is not correctly checking if the two objects are equal.

You need to either override the equals() and hashCode() methods for your WordCount object, or have it return something you want to compare, i.e:`word.getWord().equals(list[i].getWord())`

Answer (score 0):

It seems easier to use:

```
public static int search(WordCount[] list, WordCount word)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if(list[i] == word){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This checks each value in the array and compares it against the word that you specified.

Comment: This won't work, WordCount is not comparable using the == operator

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing in the current approach is that you have to create a new `WordCount` object in order to look for the count of a particular word. You could add a method like

```
public boolean hasEqualWord(WordCount other)
{
    return word.equals(other.word);
}
```

in your `WordCount` class, and use it instead of the `equals` method:

```
....
while (result < 0 && i < n)
{
    if (word.hasEqualWord(list[i])) // <--- Use it here!
    { 
    ....
    }
}
```

But I'd recommend you to rethink what you are going to model there - and how. While it is not technically "wrong" to create a class that summarizes a word and its "count", there may be more elgant solutions. For example, when this is only about counting words, you could consider a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
{
    if (tokens[i].length()>0)
    {
        Integer count = counts.get(tokens[i]);
        if (count == null)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        counts.put(tokens[i], count+1);
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can look up the number of occurrences of each word in this map:

```
String word = "SomeWord";
Integer count = counts.get(word); 
System.out.println(word+" occurred "+count+" times);
```